# What's the deep meaning in the lyrics of "Heavy Traffic" by Elton John?

Tags: meaning, slang, idioms, lyrics

In the lyrics, some pieces I couldn't understand very well:

> Shakey wake up thirsty from a night in the bar 
>      And snake hips Joe is Mr. Cool

What's `snake hips`? And, does the name `Joe` have a special meaning?

> Out on the boulevard 
>      The pimp from the Jack of Diamonds

I guess `Jack of Diamonds` is somewhere similar to Casino, yes?

> Just got another Jane Doe 
>      She just got off the last bus from Montecedo

Why `Jane Doe`? Is the guy very special?
And where is `Montecedo`?

> Sailor boys find trouble in the alien state 
>      It's one on one from Las Palmas to the Golden Gate 
>      Fly boys on the corner waiting for a ride 
>      For twenty bucks he'll pull the cork on the man inside

Why `on the corner`, but not `in the corner`? And what means `waiting for a ride`?

I'm also confused with the phrase `pull the cork on the man inside`.

> `Cause we're rolling in heavy traffic 
>      Judy's in the jump seat and Jody's in the bucket 
>      Billy likes to drive and Jackie's just high 
>      And Cindy thinks we're all gonna commit suicide

How to understand the word `rolling`?

> `Cause we're rolling in heavy traffic 
>      Yeah we're rolling in heavy traffic
>      
>      Mack he's got his Marlboros tucked up in his sleeve

FWIK, Marlboro is a brand of cigarette, yet? But how do Mack hidden Marlboro in his sleeve?

> He's shacked up in his basement making P.C.P. 
>      He used to shake the french fries

What P.C.P was Mack making?

> Down on 12th and Maine 
>      And now he stays up nights on apple juice and cocaine

How to understand `Down on 12th`?

I know I have got too many questions, but any help pointing out answers is appreciated.

Comment: I can't believe @RegDwight didn't weigh in here. :)

Comment: @Robusto: [don't ask me, I'm only the piano player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_Shoot_Me_I'm_Only_the_Piano_Player). Ask [Bernie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Taupin), it's his lyrics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting song lyrics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jack of diamonds* is also a playing card. There are four suits: hearts, diamonds, clubs and spades. *Jack* is the card between a 10 and a queen.

*Jane Doe* means unknown female person; *John Doe* is the male equivalent. It means she is a small town girl from some backwater village.

Tough guys used to roll their sleeves and put a cigarette box into the wrap, so that the box is next to biceps muscles. Google "cigarette rolled in sleeve" for pictures.

*PCP*, aka *Angel Dust* is hallucinogenic drug. *Shaking french fries* means that Mack used to work in a fast-food restaurant, which usually is poorly paid.

*Down on 12th* means *12th street*. In the United States, streets often are numbered instead of having "real" names.

Comment: Stripping the lyrics down to the dictionary level defeats the whole idea of a song. That's done in a literature/criticism class.

Comment: Perhaps pointless, as this had been closed for quite a while, but I suspect he meant "12th and **Main**". In the US at least, the central street in nearly every city is named "Main". "12th and Main" will be a downtown area just about anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

'Snake hips' is a term describing someone who is a good dancer, specifically because they are flexible. It is a kind of joke because snakes, of course, don't have hips. I don't think 'Joe' has any special significance.

'Jack of Diamonds' is probably the name of a club or casino, yes.

'On the corner' refers to the corner of a street. So they're waiting 'on the street corner'. 'In the corner' would mean they were indoors, in the corner of a room, say.

'Rolling in heavy traffic' simply means driving in heavy traffic.

Anonymous has answered the others admirably.